# Process.Start fails without ".exe" extension

Tags: vb.net, process.start

I am trying to running an executable without ".exe" extension, when I'm trying to run my ".bin" file (actually it's .exe but I renamed it with .bin for prevent confusion) It's shows to me program selector windows.

How can I avoid that?

```
    If File.Exists("client.bin") Then
        Process.Start("client.bin", param)
        delay(100)
        Terminate()
    Else
        MsgBox(Lang(6), MsgBoxStyle.Critical, TITLE)
        Terminate()
    End If
```

Comment: Windows cant RUN a BIN file.  In many cases you'll start a helper app like a DVD Burner thinking the file is an image file.  Keep it as EXE or you are confusing Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is essentially asking the operating system's runtime to handle the file. It uses the file extension to determine what it should do. For example, a `.doc` extension would be opened with Word (ultimately the process handler would pass the file path as an argument to the target application: `winword.exe {filepath}.doc`).

Windows doesn't know how to handle a `.bin` file, so it turns to you for help - hence the program selector prompt.

You can only execute an executable, just change the file extension back to `.exe`.

What confusion are you trying to prevent? For example, if you're trying to stop users from accidentally running the application, can't you move it to a different place where it might be a little harder to find?

If you really want to call it something else (and this is *really, really messy*), you could rename the file just before and after you run it. However, I would **highly recommend** you don't do this, it's really bad design!